# can I send a request via publish subscriber model

Tags: communication, broker, publisher, subscriber

My question is related to pub and sub communication model. Specifically, can I send a request via this system. for example, If I'm the publisher, can I send a request to the subscribers saying I need more information about your system or some information about a specific thing. what i know that I can only publish data, but I do not know if I can send a request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, the question is how correct is the use of the protocol for that..

Your client can pub a topic **home/xoce/readyToGetInfo/ true** and maybe all other clients subscribed to that topic can readdct to that and begin to push

**home/xoce/temperature/ 11.11**

but it looks very weird...